# REGEX: What the meaning of . followed by +?

Tags: c#, regex

Sorry to ask this question, but I'm really stuck. This code belongs to someone who already left the company. And it causing problem.

```
protected override string CleanDataLine(string line)
    {
        //the regular expression for GlobalSight log
        Regex regex = new Regex("\".+\"");
        Match match = regex.Match(line);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            string matchPart = match.Value;
            matchPart = 
                  matchPart.Replace(string.Format("\"{0}\"", 
                  Delimiter), string.Format("\"{0}\"", "*+*+"));
            matchPart = matchPart.Replace(Delimiter, '_');
            matchPart = 
                  matchPart.Replace(string.Format("\"{0}\"", "*+*+"), 
                  string.Format("\"{0}\"", Delimiter));
            line = line.Replace(match.Value, matchPart);
        }
        return line;
    }
```

I've spent to much time researching. What was he trying to accomplish?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to learn the basics of regular expressions.

Comment: I'm skeptical that you could have spent _any_ time researching and not come up with the answer. Relevant references: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html and http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html You can also drop a regex into http://regex101.com and get a breakdown of the different components and explanations of what each part does.

Comment: They've got simple Regex cheat sheets out there - I hang it up on my wall - makes life a lot easier when you need to know the basics. My favorite is [here](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1).

Comment: Debug it and see values of all variables on each line. *Spoiler* (still a guess, I strongly suggest debugging): if `line` contains a pair of double quotes, replace all occurrences of `Delimiter` with `_` not touching those that are in double quotes.

Comment: Saying "searched alot" is not enough to show effor...  Please show links that you've found to regex syntax that don't cover `.` and `+`. Note that title of the post does not match post - title contains `+?` for regex, but there is no `?` in sample :)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, are you trolling him, or did you mistake the question mark at the end of the sentence (indicating a question) for a portion of the regex?

Comment: @KirkWoll -  I'm not sure :). When I looked at the question's title `+?` looked like legitimate reason to ask (I could not see "what is `.+`" as real regex question)... I guess more trolling than really serious comment after reading and downvoting the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That regex matches

- a quote (`"`),
- followed by one or more (`+`) characters (any character except newlines (`.`), as many as possible),
- followed by a quote `"`.

It's not a very good regex. For example, in the string `foo "bar" baz "bam" boom`, it will match `"bar" baz "bam"`.

If the intention is to match a quoted string, a more appropriate regex would be `"[^"]*"`.

Comment: You must be a genius in Regex matter because that the problem I'm having. Actually, the above code is selecting two texts in quote including free text between them, just as you describe in your response. I'll try to replace his Regex by yours, to see if it will work.

Comment: @Richard77: That's a common problem, see the section "Watch out for the greediness!" in this tutorial about [quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). Also, don't forget to escape the quotes, as in `Regex regex = new Regex("\"[^\"]*\"");`.

Answer (score 2):

. is any character except \n, + means 1 or more.

So: .+ is "1 or more characters"

Answer (score 1):

The dot matches any character except line breaks.
**+** is "one or more" (equal to **{1,}**)

Answer (score 1):

```
protected override string CleanDataLine(string line)
{
    //the regular expression for GlobalSight log
    Regex regex = new Regex("\".+\"");
    Match match = regex.Match(line);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string matchPart = match.Value;
        matchPart = 
              matchPart.Replace(string.Format("\"{0}\"", 
              Delimiter), string.Format("\"{0}\"", "*+*+"));
        matchPart = matchPart.Replace(Delimiter, '_');
        matchPart = 
              matchPart.Replace(string.Format("\"{0}\"", "*+*+"), 
              string.Format("\"{0}\"", Delimiter));
        line = line.Replace(match.Value, matchPart);
    }
    return line;
}
```

`line` is just some text, could be `Hello World`, or anything really.

`new Regex("\".+\"")` the `\"` is an escaped quote, this means it's actually looking for a string to start with a double quote. `.+` means to find any character not including the new-line character one or more times.

If it does match, then he tries to figure out the part that matched by grabbing the value.

It then just becomes a normal search and replace for whatever string was matched.